# Bootstrap carousel with tooltip info

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made bootstrap carousel with fade effect - the example you can see here on [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/vKMRPrnCnb)

I added inside the carousel item - tooltip code, but it is hidden by carousel "wrapper".
Is it possible to display outside the carousel the tooltip info?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out - `overflow: visible` for `carousel-inner`class do that think.